# Wrong tensor sizes for MSEloss

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, resnet

I'm trying to train a resnet / CAE, but I'm getting an error because of the size of my tensors. I'm running the code as is, below:

```
class BasicBlock(nn.Module):
  expansion = 1

  def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, stride=1, downsample=None):
    super(BasicBlock, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = conv3x3(in_channels, out_channels, stride)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.conv2 = conv3x3(out_channels, out_channels)
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels)
    self.downsample = downsample
    self.stride = stride

  def forward(self, x):
    residual = x

    out = self.conv1(x)
    out = self.bn1(out)
    out = self.relu(out)

    out = self.conv2(out)
    out = self.bn2(out)

    if self.downsample is not None:
      residual = self.downsample(x)
  
    out += residual
    out = self.relu(out)

    return out

class Encoder(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, block, layers, num_classes=23):
    self.in_channels = 64
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()

    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    self.layer1 = self._make_layer(block, 64, layers[0], stride=1)
    self.layer2 = self._make_layer(block, 128, layers[1], stride=2)
    self.layer3 = self._make_layer(block, 256, layers[2], stride=2)
    self.layer4 = self._make_layer(block, 512, layers[3], stride=2)
    self.layer5 = self._make_layer(block, 256, layers[4], stride=2)
    self.layer6 = self._make_layer(block, 128, layers[5], stride=2)
    self.layer7 = self._make_layer(block, 64, layers[6], stride=2)
    self.layer8 = self._make_layer(block, 32, layers[7], stride=2)
    self.layer9 = self._make_layer(block, 16, layers[8], stride=2)

  def _make_layer(self, block,channels, blocks, stride=1):
      downsample = None
      if stride != 1 or self.in_channels != channels * block.expansion:
          downsample = nn.Sequential(
              nn.Conv2d(self.in_channels, channels * block.expansion,
                        kernel_size=1, stride=stride, bias=False),
              nn.BatchNorm2d(channels * block.expansion),
          )

      layers = []
      layers.append(block(self.in_channels, channels, stride, downsample))
      self.in_channels = channels * block.expansion
      for i in range(1, blocks):
          layers.append(block(self.in_channels, channels))

      return nn.Sequential(*layers)

  def forward(self, x):
      x = self.conv1(x)
      x = self.bn1(x)
      x = self.relu(x)

      x = self.layer1(x)
      print(x.shape)
      x = self.layer2(x)
      print(x.shape)
      x = self.layer3(x)
      print(x.shape)
      x = self.layer4(x)
      print(x.shape)
      x = self.layer5(x)
      x = self.layer6(x)
      print(x.shape)
      x = self.layer7(x)
      print(x.shape)
      x = self.layer8(x)
      print(x.shape)
      x = self.layer9(x)

      x = F.avg_pool2d(x, 1)
      return x



class NewDecoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(NewDecoder,self).__init__()

    self.upsample = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
    self.conv2d1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16,32,4, padding=1,stride=2)
    self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.conv2d2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32,64,4, padding=1,stride=2)
    self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.conv2d3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64,128,4, padding=1,stride=2)
    self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.conv2d4 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128,256,4, padding=1,stride=2)
    self.bn4 = nn.BatchNorm2d(256)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.conv2d5 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(256,128,4, padding=1,stride=2)
    self.bn5 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.conv2d6 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(128,64,4, padding=1,stride=2)
    self.bn6 = nn.BatchNorm2d(64)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.conv2d7 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64,32,4, padding=1,stride=2)
    self.bn7 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.conv2d8 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32,16,4, padding=1,stride=2)
    self.bn8 = nn.BatchNorm2d(16)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.conv2d9 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16,3,4, padding=1,stride=2)
    self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
  
  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.conv2d1(x)
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.bn1(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2d2(x)
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.bn2(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2d3(x)
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.bn3(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2d4(x)
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.bn4(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2d5(x)
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.bn5(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2d6(x)
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.bn6(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2d7(x)
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.bn7(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2d8(x)
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.bn8(x)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.conv2d9(x)
    print(x.shape)
    x = self.sigmoid(x)
    return(x)


criterion = nn.MSELoss().to(device)

params_to_optimize = [
    {'params': encoder.parameters()},
    {'params': decoder.parameters()}
]
optim = torch.optim.Adam(params_to_optimize, lr=0.001, weight_decay=1e-05)


def train_epoch(encoder, decoder, device, dataloader, loss_fn, optimizer):
    # Set train mode for both the encoder and the decoder
    encoder.train()
    decoder.train()
    train_loss = []
    # Iterate the dataloader (we do not need the label values, this is unsupervised learning)
    for image_batch, labels in trainloader: 
        # Move tensor to the proper device
        image_batch = image_batch.to(device)
        # Encode data
        encoded_data = encoder(image_batch)
        # Decode data
        decoded_data = decoder(encoded_data)
        # Evaluate loss
        loss = criterion(decoded_data, image_batch)
        # Backward pass
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        # Print batch loss
        #print('\t partial train loss (single batch): %f' % (loss.data))
        train_loss.append(loss.detach().cpu().numpy())

    return np.mean(train_loss)

num_epochs = 15
diz_loss = {'train_loss':[],'val_loss':[]}
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
   train_loss = train_epoch(encoder,decoder,device,trainloader,criterion,optim)
   val_loss = test_epoch(encoder,decoder,device,testloader,criterion)
   print('\n EPOCH {}/{} \t train loss {} \t val loss {}'.format(epoch + 1, num_epochs,train_loss,val_loss))
   diz_loss['train_loss'].append(train_loss)
   diz_loss['val_loss'].append(val_loss)
   plot_ae_outputs(encoder,decoder,n=10)
```

When I run this code, I get this output (I have left the prints so you can see the shape of the tensors):

```
torch.Size([256, 64, 32, 32])
torch.Size([256, 128, 16, 16])
torch.Size([256, 256, 8, 8])
torch.Size([256, 512, 4, 4])
torch.Size([256, 128, 1, 1])
torch.Size([256, 64, 1, 1])
torch.Size([256, 32, 1, 1])
torch.Size([256, 32, 2, 2])
torch.Size([256, 64, 4, 4])
torch.Size([256, 128, 8, 8])
torch.Size([256, 256, 16, 16])
torch.Size([256, 128, 32, 32])
torch.Size([256, 64, 64, 64])
torch.Size([256, 32, 128, 128])
torch.Size([256, 16, 256, 256])
torch.Size([256, 3, 512, 512])
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:536: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([256, 3, 32, 32])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([256, 3, 512, 512])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
```

I know the error is appearing because the shape of my tensor isn't matching the original image of 3,32,32, but I'm unsure of how to actually get them to match.

Comment: Have you tried resizing the decoded (output) image? You need it to match the original one. Alternatively you can modify the ouput layer to match the original dimension.

Comment: @Deusy94 you mean trying decoded_data.reshape(256,3,32,32)?

Comment: Not really, you need to apply an image resize to that, using some interpolation. You can use transform.resize from torchvision.

Comment: @Deusy94 hmm, i have not tried that, and im not quite sure how that works tbh, but I will try and look into it

Comment: Could you please provide the context of the problem? why are you generating a 512*512 image for 32*32 target?

Comment: @coder00 Well i dont want to generate 512*512, but im not sure how to get it doen to 32*32

Comment: You can delete the extra layers from your decoder, if you look carefully at the shape of your outputs, you got `torch.Size([256, 128, 32, 32])`, just change the number of channels of this layer to 3. I think it will be better for the network. However, it seems that you are using a big network for small inputs.

Comment: I suggest to give names to the `print`, for example     `print(f"conv2d9 {x.shape}")`